# database stucture to implement users table

Tags: mysql

how can i design database for user when i have 3 type of users administrator and free member and golden member and golden member will be for a period of time, 30 day 45 day like that,
how can i design the structure i implementing a file sharing system

Answer (score 0):

I would just have a single user table, with a field identifying the user type with a code of some sort.  Then, have a process that comes through and looks for all golden members that are older than 30 days and deletes or deactivates them.

Answer (score 0):

I would design it with 2 tables - first to carry the user information along with the level of membership (free, golden), and second to have the validity against the membership type. In your code you'd do the math of determining if the access is valid or not by looking up the validity from the validity table. This will give you flexibility to add more levels down the road if you want to. Here is a very, very rough schema of what I am inferring to:

```
mysql> desc members;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| name        | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| membership  | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> desc memberships;
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| name     | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| validity | int(3)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```